# Write NumPy array contents to a file in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, io

I have a NumPy array that I'm trying to write to a file

```
outfile.write(str(myarray))
```

But, I get something that looks like this:

```
[    4.275000000e01   2.345000000e01  3.2135000000e-02    ]
```

My requirements are:

1. To write the data within the array (and not the array braces [])
2. To write the data with a certain number of trailing decimal places (say 6)

Normally, **#2** would not be that hard, but I'm not sure how to handle it in conjunction with **#1**.

I also want to write the array on one line as a row. like this:

```
4.27500000  2.34500000  0.03213500000
```

Comment: FIrst hit on a popular search engine: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.io.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`savetxt` does the equivalent of:

```
In [631]: x=np.array([4.275000000e01,   2.345000000e01,  3.2135000000e-02])

In [632]: '%10.6f %10.6f %10.6f'%tuple(x)
Out[632]: ' 42.750000  23.450000   0.032135'

In [642]: outfile.write((' '.join(['%10.6f ']*x.size)+'\n\n') % tuple(x))
42.750000   23.450000    0.032135
```

It turns your one-dimensional array into a tuple and passes it off to the format statement, with a format specification for each item in the array.

Comment: Yes! Thank you!!! I'm really not sure why this needs to be so difficult. In FORTRAN, this would be trivial.

Comment: In FORTRAN, at least the versions I first learned, you HAD to be explicit about the format.  It doesn't seem as trivial in Python because we normally don't have to deal with those details.

Answer (score 2):

If by writing to a file you mean text file, then use [numpy.savetxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html):

```
import numpy as np
my_array = np.random.rand(10,4)
np.savetxt('my_filenmame', my_array, fmt='%4.6f', delimiter=' ')
```

would write `my_array` to `my_filename` with up to six decimal digits leaving a white space in between them.

**After the OP's edit:** if you want to write the whole array to one line, make sure your array has only one row:

```
np.savetxt('my_filenmame', my_array.reshape(1,rows*cols), fmt='%4.6f', delimiter=' ')
```

where in this case `rows=10` and `cols=4`. Or use `ravel` or `flatten` (see also [Harpal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32082961/write-numpy-array-contents-to-a-file-in-python/32083467#32083467), although that does not answer the decimal precision issue)

```
np.savetxt('my_filenmame', my_array.ravel(), fmt='%4.6f', delimiter=' ', newline=' ')
```

Comment: Thanks, that does seem to help... Now, is there a way to print out the list/array on one row in my file?

Comment: What do you mean by "print out the list/array on one row in my file". Do you want to read only one line from the file and print it?

Comment: I have a long array that I want to print out on one line in my output file (see edit in OP). I don't want one number per line, I want all the numbers on one line. @romeric

Comment: Okay, then what is the shape of your array? If it is a one-dimensional array i.e. only one row `savetxt` should take care of that for you, otherwise use either `ravel` or `flatten` to flatten the the array and then write to file.

Comment: My array has shape (51,). Your solution doesn't seem to work for me. The savetxt command puts out each value of the array in a new line. ravel or flatten don't seem to do anything, I guess because I already have a 1D array.

Comment: I have updated the answer. use `my_array.reshape(1,51)` instead of just `my_array`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]])
>>> a
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])
>>> b = a.flatten()
>>> b
array([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3])
>>> >>> np.savetxt("array.txt",b,delimiter=' ',newline=' ')
```

Edited to write on a single line